# TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not int (Python)

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror, superclass

I am trying to create a `GroupMessage` class that inherits some of its attributes from the main `Chat` class. I am getting an error at the `super(chat_id, user1).__init__()` line. I am unable to fix it!

```
class Chats(object):
    def __init__(self, chat_id, user1):
        self.id = chat_id
        self.initiator = user1
        self.messages = {}  # Key is current date/time; value is a list of messages


class GroupMessage(Chats):
    def __init__(self, chat_id, user1, group_name, message):
        super(chat_id, user1).__init__()
        self.group = group
        self.messages[datetime.datetime.now()] = self.messages[datetime.datetime.now()].append(message)
```

Upon instantiating `GroupMessage`, I get an error!

```
Chat_group = GroupMessage(1, "Batool","AI_group","Text Message")
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not int
```

Comment: Well, as it says, you need to pass a type as the first argument, not an integer. Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)?

Comment: that's not how it's done... change your call to `super` with: `super().__init__(chat_id, user1)`

Comment: @alfasin, I had initially done that way but got this error: TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given).

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6.  For 2.x try `super(GroupMessage,
 self).__init__(chat_id, user1)`

Comment: @Batool That is because you are using Python 2.x. With Python 2.x you have to pass the base class name as first parameter to the `super`

Comment: @kindall thank you for pointing me to the documentation.

Comment: @wwii thank you for pointing this out. It fixed it!

Comment: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @wwii Thanks! I did not know python 2.7 will be gone this soon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should do instead of `super(chat_id, user1).__init__()` you should do:

```
super().__init__(chat_id, user1) # Work in Python 3.6
super(GroupMessage, self).__init__(chat_id, user1) # Work in Python 2.7
```

or

```
Chats.__init__(self, chat_id, user1)
```

This last option is not recommended if exist change that your class hierarchy change in the future. I really don't like it for others motive but still worth it a mention.

Comment: @gsi-frank: Is there a way to uses some common syntax that will be well interpreted whether using python 3.x or python 2.7? In what related to the super directive?